# Lattice in R: Bottom of bar charts not aligned with x=0

Tags: r, alignment, bar-chart, lattice

I tried making a simple bar chart using the `barchart` function from the Lattice library with the following code

```
plot_sum_h <- barchart(event~value|incidence, data=msum_h_combo,
                     groups=variable,
                     ylab="Event", xlab="", layout=c(2,1),
                     main="Total Number of Casualities",
                     scales=list(y=list(relation="same"),
                                 x=list(relation="free"))
                 )
```

and got 
<strike>[**this graph**](https://github.com/SamanthaLui/RepData_PeerAssessment2/blob/master/Rplot.png).</strike> <sup>Links not working anymore.</sup>

The bottoms of the bars, which should be aligned with the zero mark on the x-axis are behind `x=0`. Does anyone have any idea what might have gone wrong? Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can set that by setting `limits` on the x-axis. In your `scales` argument you can do

```
x=list(relation="free", limits= list(c(0,2000),c(0.20000)) )
```

In the limits list this will set the scales for each panel (when you use `relation="free"`)

That will put the edge of the graph at 0, and I just guessed what would be good for the upper limits. You could also set limits like `=c( 0,( 1.1*max(values) ))` Which would set the max at 110% of the maximum of its `Value` in each panel.

Comment: Thanks, John. Unfortunately my program was too stubborn to do what it should be doing even with your suggestion. I guess possibly it was due to the fact that the events for the y-values are of type character. I played around with the code a bit more afterward and finally found that adding "origin = 0" into the parameter gives the desired result. Thank you again for your time and suggestion.